# Volume buttons do not work after AVAudioRecorder recording

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

Before recording Audio, the volume buttons work fine during AVAudioPlayer playing session.
As soon as I record audio with AVAudioRecorder, and I come back to the AudioPlayer (they are in different ViewControllers), the volume buttons do not work any more.

I set the AVAudioSession active and set the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord during recording and to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback during the playback.

I have no idea what else I can set to influent this behaviour.

I hope someone can give me some hint for a possible solution of this problem.

Comment: Did you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my project i'm changing AVAudioSession from Record to Playback and back again constantly and when in Playback mode volume buttons enabled and working. When i change audio session mode from pure Record to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord then volume buttons works always.